# I'm receiving "Cannot read property 'offices' of undefined" error for a dropdown

Tags: javascript, vue.js

As far as I can tell everything is set up correctly but it's still throwing this error. I know that the data is there as I've done the same set up in previous iterations of this and it has worked perfectly. Is there something I am missing???

Or am I going about this the wrong way?

```
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Escrow Office</label>
        <v-select
            class="highlights"
            :options="select.offices"
            :on-change="selectOffice"
            :searchable="false"
            :clear-search-on-select="false"
            v-model="select.officeSelected"
        ></v-select>
      </div>
    </div>
data() {
  return {
    now: new Date().toISOString(),
    document: {
      escrow_office_id: 1,
    }
  }
},
methods: {
  init(){
    if(this.listing != null) {
            getEscrow() {
               this.page.loading = true;
               axios.get('/api/v2/escrows/' + this.page.id, {headers: {'Authorization': 
               'Bearer ' + this.$root.access_token}})
            .then(response => {
               this.escrow = response.data.escrow;
               this.document.escrow_office_id = response.data.escrow.escrow_office_id;
               this.select.officeSelected = this.select.offices.find(x => x.value === 
               this.form.escrow_office_id);
            })
            .catch(e => {
             var err = (!!e.response ? (!!e.response.data ? (!!e.response.data.error ? 
             e.response.data.error : '') : '') : '');
              if (err != "") this.$noty.error("Error: " + err);
              else this.$noty.error("Cannot call getEscrow()");
            })
            .finally(() => {
            this.page.loading = false;
      });
  },
  getShared() {
    this.select.offices = this.$root.shared.escrow_offices;
  },
  selectOffice(option) {
    this.select.officeSelected = option;
    this.document.escrow_office_id = option.value;
  },
},
    }
  }
}

mounted() {
  this.getShared();
  this.getEscrow();
  setTimeout(() => { this.loaded = true; }, 1000);
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return `select` from your data function.

```
data() {
    return {
        select: // Your select object
        now: new Date().toISOString(),
        document: {
            escrow_office_id: 1
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Spot on Joshua. I hadn't seen that mistake. Thanks.